# How display last_name from employees table contain 'a' or 'o' or 'e' letter?

Tags: sql

I want to display from the employees table, only rows where the last_name contains the letters a, o, or e. I wrote the query below but it doesn't work.

```
select last_name from Hr.employees where last_name like '%a,o,e';
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (String functions may differ...)

Comment: What about a `select last_name form Hr.employees where last_name like '%a%' or last_name like '%o%' or last_name like '%e%'` ?;

Comment: you can use regex as well. For example - ` REGEXP_LIKE( first_name, 'aoe' )` in oracle.

Comment: All the three i.e(a, e, o) letter included in single name or any of these?
SELECT last_name  FROM employees WHERE last_name  like '%a%' OR  last_name  like '%e%' OR  last_name  like  '%o%';

Answer (score 3):

As you are not closing your list with a percentage sign, your list will search only for names ending with the named letters.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM Hr.employees
WHERE last_name LIKE '%a%' 
OR last_name LIKE '%o%'
OR last_name LIKE '%e%'
```

Read more on usage of LIKE operator [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: 'Please mark this answer as solve in case it helped you.' - I would say it's a bit lame to beg for this when the question is quite easy and has already been answered in the EXACT same way...

Comment: @AndreiXwe hey, sorry - though when I entered my Query I didn't see any other answers yet. I searched for some good explanations on the web to explain OP on solving the issue in the future, rather than having a quick solution too. As said, didn't see any post from you...

Comment: To be fair, I also didn't see there was a comment saying the same thing, but that was seconds before, not minutes :D

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select last_name from Hr.employees 
where last_name like '%a%' or last_name like '%e%' or last_name like '%o%';
```